# Volume of polar body defined by $n$ points in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: convex-geometry

Suppose I have $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Is there an expression for the volume of the following set:

$$
\{x \in \mathbb R^n : |x \cdot v_i| \leq 1 \text{ for all } i\}
$$

?

My understanding is that this is the polar set of $\{ \pm v_1, \ldots, \pm v_n\}$.

Comment: This set is a parallelepiped similar to the one spanned by the $v_i$.

Comment: Ah! If $V$ is $n\times n$ and has $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ as its rows, and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ denote the columns of $V^{-1}$, then the parallelepiped is generated by $\{ \pm w_1, \ldots, \pm w_n\}$.